# memcatch in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

how to use memcatch in ruby on rails  i installed cached_model what next do for memcached for database so every time no need to go for fetch data from database

Comment: Your question seems a little too generic at this point. Have you read the Rails guides for caching yet? That might help you narrow it down to a tangible question. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Comment: You should also have memcached installed. It is a separate process from your Rails app, just like the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some useful web pages out there that can get you started. For example:

- http://nubyonrails.com/articles/memcached-basics-for-rails
- http://www.ridingtheclutch.com/2009/01/08/cache-anything-easily-with-rails-and-memcached.html
- http://www.slideshare.net/guestac752c/caching-memcached-and-rails
- http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2008/6/9/rails-2-1-now-with-better-integrated-caching

Google for *rails memcache*. Then, kick back for some good readin'.